# flutter_test from sdk is forbidden

Tags: xml, sdk, flutter-test

I try to run my application using flutter virtual device in vs code but it come up with this error

Because every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on xml 3.5.0 which doesn't match any versions, flutter_test from sdk is forbidden.
So, because newyearapp depends on flutter_test any from sdk, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because newyearapp depends on flutter_test any from sdk, version solving failed.)

i tried several times to solve this problem but I can't can someone help to me?

Answer (score 1):

I solved by adding following in the pubspec.yaml

```
dependency_overrides:
  xml: ^4.1.0 # version that is available in your project
  petitparser: ^3.0.0
```

> flutter_test from sdk depends on xml 3.5.0 which doesn't match any versions, flutter_test from sdk is forbidden

It seems flutter_test is unable to find xml 3.5.0. So add `xml: ^4.1.0` in `dependencies:` if you haven't already.

Here is the [github link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21338) to the given issue.